# highcharter - how can I display my data values in the countries on the map?

Tags: r

**My Set-up:** I am currently trying to use an interactive map to show the different number of cases of SARS by country through a world map. Rather than trying on Shiny, I attempted to do it on a flexdashboard on R Markdown. Currently, I have a data set with two columns: "Country" and "total". Country shows which country it is while "total" shows the number of cases of SARS. "Country" is a factor object while "total" is numeric.

**Now my question is:** I have set-up and used the sample geojson world map, however none of the values of my data set is being inputted into the world map I used. How should I go about displaying my values on the maps? Is this because the "worldgeojson" map cannot correctly read the countries in my data set?

**My code currently is:**

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Number of Cases of SARS in the World") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Source: SARS.csv") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, countries,
                 name = "Country",
                 value = "total",
                 joinBy = c("woename", "Country")) %>% 
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you share which packages you used and the data? The ideal solution would be creating a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/). It's difficult to help you at the moment.

Comment: Some packages I used include: library(tidyverse) - like dplyr to help clean my data, library(flexdashboard) - to create a flex dashboard for rmd, and library(highcharter) - to use for mapping. I am currently relatively still new to R, therefore I'm not familiar with creating a reprex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your data, it is unclear what the problem might be.

However, here is a working example you could use.

```
library(highcharter)

countries <- data.frame(
  Country = c("Canada", "China", "France"),
  Total = c(251, 5327, 7)
)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Number of Cases of SARS in the World") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text = "Source: SARS.csv") %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(worldgeojson, countries,
                    name = "SARS Cases",
                    value = "Total",
                    joinBy = c("name", "Country")) %>% 
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T)
```

**Map**

[image: SARS Cases Map]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! I noticed that the difference from my code with yours is simply in joinBy, the first input was not "woename", but rather "name" fixed the problem. I thought using "woename" (Where on Earth) would make sense, however just using "name" fixed this issue. Appreciate the help :)